# Set a select option by it's position in the list with iMacros

Tags: imacros

I want to **select the nth option** *(for example, the second)*, regardless of which the value is.

`TAG TYPE=SELECT ... CONTENT=(the second option)`

How may I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [related wiki page](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#Special_TAG_Commands_for_Drop_Down_Menus) and you can find this way:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ... CONTENT=#2
```